# Calculate time difference in hours

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

This is supposed to be a query for a virtual machine in Amazon EC2, it lists the instances by it's instanceID and LaunchTime (when it was turned up) - and I want to calculate another column that is it's LaunchTime - Current Date/Time to get a "uptime" statistic called HoursSinceBoot.

```
#get instances
$instances = foreach($i in (get-ec2instance)) {$i.RunningInstance | Select-Object InstanceId,LaunchTime}
$instances | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name HoursSinceBoot -value (Foreach-object -inputobject     $instances {New-TimeSpan -End (get-date) -Start $_.LaunchTime} | select -expandproperty hours)
$instances
```

This is the error I get the error below, which seems to indicate Launchtime is not a datetime type, which sure enough when I run a get-member it sure as crap is.  Now I know if I run $*[0].LaunchTime this code will work, but for some reason using simply the $* variable it all goes to hell.  I've tried a few date time conversion techniques like [datetime] but they have similar error "can't convert to type datetime" consequences.

```
New-TimeSpan : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.DateTime' required by parameter 'Start'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\xxx\powershell\aws-watchdog.ps1:3 char:149
+ ... t-date) -Start $_.LaunchTime} | select -expandproperty hours)
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand
```

Comment: Do not trust get-member unless you use the form "get-member -inputObject $objectName". If you have a collection of DateTimes and pipe this to get-member (ie $colDateTimes | get-member), it will report DateTimes. Fact that error mentions 'System.Object[]' suggests you are dealing with an array/collection here.

Comment: When calculating differences between two datetimes I generally use the form "($EndTime - $StartTime).TotalHours", which is simpler then declaring new TimeSpan objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off calculating the new `HoursSinceBoot` property as part of your select.

Here's an example:

```
PS C:\> $launchData = Get-EC2Instance | `
                      % { $_.RunningInstance } | `
                      Select-Object InstanceId, LaunchTime, @{Name='HoursSinceBoot'; Expression={ ((Get-Date)-$_.LaunchTime).TotalHours } }
PS C:\> $launchData | Format-Table -AutoSize

InstanceId LaunchTime              HoursSinceBoot
---------- ----------              --------------
i-abcd1234 6/11/2014 11:14:39 AM 1061.46170712353
i-efgh5678 7/11/2014 11:02:24 AM 341.665873790194
```

What's happening here:

- [Get-EC2Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2Instance.html) is piped into Foreach-Object (aliased by the percent symbol), which pulls the [RunningInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_EC2_Model_RunningInstance.htm) property off of each EC2 reservation object.
- We pipe each RunningInstance to `Select-Object` to select InstanceId and LaunchTime, and then generate a new property called HoursSinceBoot.
- There are parenthesis inside the expression as a matter of order-of-operations.  It allows us to evaluate the current date before subtracting from LaunchTime, and the subtracted value before attempting to extract the `TotalHours` property from the generated DateTime.
- I incorporated @andyb's suggestion for calculating DateTime difference.

Also, for trivia's sake... you can double-check that value on the AWS console by checking under the Description tab of an EC2 instance:

[image: An image of a snippet of the AWS console, describing the launch time of one of my EC2 instances.]